# How to center a table in the screen html?

Tags: html, css

I have this table with some data [image]

I want it to be it in the center of the screen. How do I do that in CSS? I have tried `margin: 2px auto;` and stuff, but they just shrink the size of the table?

Here's my code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins:wght@300;500&family=Roboto+Mono:wght@700&family=Smooch+Sans:wght@300;900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anek+Latin:wght@600&family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins:wght@300;500&family=Roboto+Mono:wght@700&family=Smooch+Sans:wght@300;900&display=swap');
td {
  font-family: 'Anek Latin', sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: rgba(43, 215, 52, 0.606);
  border-radius: 7px;
  outline: #8B8000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(43, 215, 52, 0.606), green, olive, #8B8000, #676d42);
}

th {
  border: 2px solid rgba(158, 176, 114, 0.238);
  background-color: rgba(155, 205, 54, 0.793);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-image: linear-gradient(olive, #4b5320, #676d42, #8B8000, #5e6828);
  font-family: 'Anek Latin', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 7px;
  outline: black;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="11">Student's Name</th>
      <th colspan="3">Roll no.</th>
      <th colspan="3">Marks Obtained (out of 720)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="11">SOYEB AFTAB</td>
      <td colspan="3">5049</td>
      <td colspan="3">720</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="11">AKANSHA SINGH</td>
      <td colspan="3">1083</td>
      <td colspan="3">720</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="11"><small>TUMMALA SNIKITHA</small></td>
      <td colspan="3">2291</td>
      <td colspan="3">715</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="11">VINEET SHARMA</td>
      <td colspan="3">5561</td>
      <td colspan="3">715</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="11">KARTHIK REDDY</td>
      <td colspan="3">4153</td>
      <td colspan="3">710</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="11">GURIKIRAT SINGH</td>
      <td colspan="3">9201</td>
      <td colspan="3">624</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="11">AYSHA SINGH</td>
      <td colspan="3">1134</td>
      <td colspan="3">555</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="11">SRIJAN REDDY</td>
      <td colspan="3">3171</td>
      <td colspan="3">549</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="11">AMAN SANNI</td>
      <td colspan="3">4278</td>
      <td colspan="3">500</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>
```

I guess the margin thing doesn't work because of the div? Should I remove the div or is there a way to center it with the div?

Comment: `table{margin: 2px auto;}` should work,please provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think because the table is in a ```<div>```, it doesn't work?

Comment: Looks like it is in the center to me. Equal margins on the left and the right.

Comment: Doesn't for me though

Comment: If you are trying to ask how to put things in the vertical middle (and not horizontally which is what most people mean when they say center) then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-can-i-vertically-center-a-div-element-for-all-browsers-using-css is a duplicate.

Comment: I am not talking about horizontal and vertical, I want it to be in the center of webpage.

Comment: @DebarkaNaskar — Umm. What? I don't think you understand the meaning of the words horizontal and vertical. You can't centre something without doing so along some axis (and it isn't like there is any other content on the page for you to centre it along the z-axis!)

Comment: Nah, leave my dumb comment. Is there a way to adjust the x and y pos of my table?

Comment: So you *do* mean the vertical. I pointed you at a duplicate question which covers that two comments ago.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say with vertical and horizontal. I just wanted to know how to change the x and y positions of a table.

Comment: x is horizontal. y is vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins:wght@300;500&family=Roboto+Mono:wght@700&family=Smooch+Sans:wght@300;900&display=swap');
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anek+Latin:wght@600&family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins:wght@300;500&family=Roboto+Mono:wght@700&family=Smooch+Sans:wght@300;900&display=swap');
        td {
          font-family: 'Anek Latin', sans-serif;
          border: 2px solid white;
          background-color: rgba(43, 215, 52, 0.606);
          border-radius: 7px;
          outline: #8B8000;
          background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(43, 215, 52, 0.606), green, olive, #8B8000, #676d42);
        }

        th {
          border: 2px solid rgba(158, 176, 114, 0.238);
          background-color: rgba(155, 205, 54, 0.793);
          background-blend-mode: multiply;
          background-image: linear-gradient(olive, #4b5320, #676d42, #8B8000, #5e6828);
          font-family: 'Anek Latin', sans-serif;
          border-radius: 7px;
          outline: black;
        }

        table {
          border: 1px solid white;
          /* margin-left: auto; */
          /* margin-right: auto; */
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 500px;
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 20px;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .container {
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="11">Student's Name</th>
            <th colspan="3">Roll no.</th>
            <th colspan="3">Marks Obtained (out of 720)</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="11">SOYEB AFTAB</td>
            <td colspan="3">5049</td>
            <td colspan="3">720</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="11">AKANSHA SINGH</td>
            <td colspan="3">1083</td>
            <td colspan="3">720</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="11"><small>TUMMALA SNIKITHA</small></td>
            <td colspan="3">2291</td>
            <td colspan="3">715</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="11">VINEET SHARMA</td>
            <td colspan="3">5561</td>
            <td colspan="3">715</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="11">KARTHIK REDDY</td>
            <td colspan="3">4153</td>
            <td colspan="3">710</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="11">GURIKIRAT SINGH</td>
            <td colspan="3">9201</td>
            <td colspan="3">624</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="11">AYSHA SINGH</td>
            <td colspan="3">1134</td>
            <td colspan="3">555</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="11">SRIJAN REDDY</td>
            <td colspan="3">3171</td>
            <td colspan="3">549</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="11">AMAN SANNI</td>
            <td colspan="3">4278</td>
            <td colspan="3">500</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div>
</body>
</html>
```

Add class to your container div:

```
<div class="container">
        <table>
```

Then just remove unnecessary margins in table and use container as flex (you need to setup height have vertical alignment work) using this lines:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid white;
  /* margin-left: auto; */
  /* margin-right: auto; */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```html
  <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="11">Student's Name</th>
          <th colspan="3">Roll no.</th>
          <th colspan="3">Marks Obtained (out of 720)</th>
        </tr>
       ...
      </table>
      <div>
```

Comment: I converted your code into a live demo. It doesn't work. The table remains left aligned.

Comment: last row: </div>, not <div>. my error...

Comment: and it's ok, i tested

Comment: Seriously, you can click "Run code snippet" in your answer and see that it **does not work**. It is not "ok".

Comment: <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="11">Student's Name</th>
          <th colspan="3">Roll no.</th>
          <th colspan="3">Marks Obtained (out of 720)</th>
        </tr>
       ...
      </table>
      </div>

Comment: You can edit your answer to fix that typo and see that it **still** does not work.

Comment: I copy from your text, and last row, you have "<div>", and must be "</div>". If you put </div>, to close that opened <div>, it will work.

Comment: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php

Comment: You have not copied from my text. I haven't written any code on this question or your answer.

Comment: That link doesn't appear remotely relevant.

Comment: <html><head>...</head><body><div style="..."><table>...</table></div></body>

Comment: Spewing contextless code into the comments isn't going to fix the live demo in your answer.